# How can I create a new google application using gcm instead of fcm?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Google now wants me to use fcm instead of gcm for cloud messaging.
I need to create a simple proof of concept google application using the old gcm api to help diagnose a problem with my main application. 
But when I go to the google developer console, the option to add the gcm api is now a link to the firebase setup pages. I can't see any way to access the original API. 
Is anyone else in this position?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Google Cloud Messaging guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm), Google hasn't remove it yet. 
You can also check the [Code Samples page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/samples) for your reference wether it be Android or iOS